# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null. Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Reply)

Tags: flutter

#this is my model class where the error is pointing at,the error is E/flutter (29710): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (29710): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29710): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Reply)

```
   import 'dart:convert';

StudentHomeworkreply studentHomeworkreplyFromJson(String str) => StudentHomeworkreply.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String studentHomeworkreplyToJson(StudentHomeworkreply data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class StudentHomeworkreply {
  StudentHomeworkreply({
    this.id,
    this.schoolid,
    this.classid,
    this.subjectid,
    this.title,
    this.teacherId,
    this.sectionId,
    this.content,
    this.submissionDate,
    this.filelinks,
    this.filenames,
    this.fileUniquenames,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.students,
  });

  int id;
  String schoolid;
  String classid;
  String subjectid;
  String title;
  String teacherId;
  String sectionId;
  String content;
  DateTime submissionDate;
  String filelinks;
  String filenames;
  String fileUniquenames;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;
  List<Student> students;

  factory StudentHomeworkreply.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StudentHomeworkreply(
    id: json["id"],
    schoolid: json["schoolid"],
    classid: json["CLASSID"],
    subjectid: json["SUBJECTID"],
    title: json["title"],
    teacherId: json["teacher_id"],
    sectionId: json["section_id"],
    content: json["CONTENT"],
    submissionDate: DateTime.parse(json["submission_date"]),
    filelinks: json["filelinks"],
    filenames: json["filenames"],
    fileUniquenames: json["fileUniquenames"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
    updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    students: List<Student>.from(json["students"].map((x) => Student.fromJson(x))).toList(), //this is the place the error is pointing.........
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "schoolid": schoolid,
    "CLASSID": classid,
    "SUBJECTID": subjectid,
    "title": title,
    "teacher_id": teacherId,
    "section_id": sectionId,
    "CONTENT": content,
    "submission_date": "${submissionDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${submissionDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${submissionDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
    "filelinks": filelinks,
    "filenames": filenames,
    "fileUniquenames": fileUniquenames,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    "students": List<dynamic>.from(students.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Student {
  Student({
    this.stname,
    this.rollno,
    this.regno,
    this.homeworkStatus,
    this.replies,
  });

  String stname;
  int rollno;
  String regno;
  HomeworkStatus homeworkStatus;
  List<Reply> replies;

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Student(
    stname: json["STNAME"],
    rollno: json["ROLLNO"],
    regno: json["REGNO"],
    homeworkStatus: homeworkStatusValues.map[json["homeworkStatus"]],
    replies:List<Reply>.from(json["replies"].map((x) => Reply.fromJson(x))).toList() //this is the place the error is pointing.........
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "STNAME": stname,
    "ROLLNO": rollno,
    "REGNO": regno,
    "homeworkStatus": homeworkStatusValues.reverse[homeworkStatus],
    "replies":replies!=null??List<dynamic>.from(replies.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList()),
  };
}

enum HomeworkStatus { COMPLETED, PENDING }

final homeworkStatusValues = EnumValues({
  "completed": HomeworkStatus.COMPLETED,
  "pending": HomeworkStatus.PENDING
});

class Reply {
  Reply({
    this.comments,
    this.id,
    this.schoolid,
    this.filenames,
    this.homeworkId,
    this.filelinks,
    this.fileUniquenames,
    this.homeworkStatus,
    this.regno,
    this.teacherId,
    this.replyFrom,
    this.status,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  String comments;
  int id;
  String schoolid;
  String filenames;
  int homeworkId;
  String filelinks;
  String fileUniquenames;
  String homeworkStatus;
  String regno;
  String teacherId;
  String replyFrom;
  String status;
  DateTime createdAt;

  factory Reply.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Reply(
    comments: json["comments"],
    id: json["id"],
    schoolid: json["schoolid"],
    filenames: json["filenames"],
    homeworkId: json["homework_id"],
    filelinks: json["filelinks"],
    fileUniquenames: json["fileUniquenames"],
    homeworkStatus: json["homework_status"],
    regno: json["regno"],
    teacherId: json["teacher_id"] == null ? null : json["teacher_id"],
    replyFrom: json["reply_from"],
    status: json["status"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "comments": comments,
    "id": id,
    "schoolid": schoolid,
    "filenames": filenames,
    "homework_id": homeworkId,
    "filelinks": filelinks,
    "fileUniquenames": fileUniquenames,
    "homework_status": homeworkStatus,
    "regno": regno,
    "teacher_id": teacherId == null ? null : teacherId,
    "reply_from": replyFrom,
    "status": status,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is located on one of the `.map` invocation in the code. Somewhere, the object on which you call `map` is `null`, hence the error.

Comment: yes and in exact 2 places i have mentioned which place the error is saying in rightside can you see that?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't see. Knowing that, the error means that `json["replies"]` and/or `json["students"]` are `null`. You have to check that they are not null before calling `map`, and also probably handle the case in which they are indeed `null`

Comment: ok i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.from` for creating a list, it shouldn't have `toList()` at the end.

Change this line.

```
students: List<Student>.from(json["students"].map((x) => Student.fromJson(x))).toList(),
```

#### To one of these:

##### First:

```
students: List<Student>.from(json["students"].map((x) => Student.fromJson(x))),
```

##### Or:

```
students: (json["students"] as List).map((i) => Student.fromJson(i)).toList(),
```